# How do I export the data under state to another file?(react-native)

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I want to export the 'hscnumber' variable here to another file. How can I do it?

```js
export default class test extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.getData();
    this.state = {
      h:0,
      hscnumber:0,
   };
  }
```

Comment: What do you mean another file? you mean another component?

Comment: I'll export it for use on another page.

Answer (score 0):

By another file you mean another screen and you are using react navigation then you can use react Navigation's params to pass the data from screen to screen

`props.navigation.navigate("screen2",{data:hscnumber})`

And on screen 2

`console.log("mydata",props.route.params.data)`

If you want to pass data to components you can simply pass it by props